# system 'ArgumentException' occurred in system.data.dll

Tags: mysql

My Question is can I pass the string to MySqlConnection this way??
The Error is in this Line below in the code "MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myconnstr);"
It worked for SQLConnection but not for MySqlConnection ... is it not possibl?
kindly help me With the right solution
thanks!

string myconnstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ConnectionString;
        //Selecting Data from databse

```
    public DataTable Select()
    {

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(myconnstr);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Member";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            conn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: My App.config is:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="connstr" 
         connectionString="Data Sourcer=localhost;Initial Catalog=ABCtest; username=root;password=" />
      
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: MySQL uses different connection strings than SQL Server

Comment: @HamzaKhan Please add the full exception message to your question.